Pybit Orders: placing partial tp/sl
When placing an order on the bybit testnet:
https://testnet.bybit.com/
The filled Partial tp/sl are not taken into account by the server/exchange on Bybit side.
The order is the following:
   open_position = session.place_order(
        category="linear",
        symbol=symbol,
        side="Buy",
        orderType="Market",
        qty=0.02,
        price = str(current_price),
        timeInForce="GTC",
        takeProfit=  str(tp) ,
        stopLoss=  str(sl) ,
        tpslMode = "Partial",
        tpLimitPrice= str(tpLimitPrice) ,
        slLimitPrice= str(slLimitPrice) ,
        slOrderType= "Limit",
        tpOrderType= "Limit",
    )

when I getting the created position I obtain the following values:
get position

{'retCode': 0, 'retMsg': 'OK', 'result': {'nextPageCursor': 'BTCUSDT%2C1716196294406%2C0', 'category': 'linear', 'list': [
{'symbol': 'BTCUSDT', 'leverage': '10', 'autoAddMargin': 0, 'avgPrice': '66879', 'liqPrice': '', 'riskLimitValue': '2000000', 'takeProfit': '', 'positionValue': '2675.16', 'isReduceOnly': False, 'tpslMode': 'Full', 'riskId': 1, 'trailingStop': '0', 'unrealisedPnl': '-0.88', 'markPrice': '66857', 'adlRankIndicator': 1, 'cumRealisedPnl': '-1219.55306143', 'positionMM': '14.7000042', 'createdTime': '1713947193915', 'positionIdx': 0, 'positionIM': '268.8402042', 'seq': 9224765210, 'updatedTime': '1716196294406', 'side': 'Buy', 'bustPrice': '', 'positionBalance': '0', 'leverageSysUpdatedTime': '', 'curRealisedPnl': '-0.535032', 'size': '0.04', 'positionStatus': 'Normal', 'mmrSysUpdatedTime': '', 'stopLoss': '', 'tradeMode': 0, 'sessionAvgPrice': ''}
]}, 'retExtInfo': {}, 'time': 1716196302813}
positionValue usdt: 2675.16
takeProfit usdt:
stopLoss usdt:
tpslMode usdt: Full
size usdt: 0.04
cumRealisedPnl usdt: -1219.55306143
tradeMode usdt: 0

As we can see not only the exchange did not took the partial tp/sl into account (tpslMode is in Full) but it did not even consider the regular tp/sl.
On the opposite if I remove the partial part as well as the partial tp/sl. The exchange take the regular tp/sl into account.
What am I missing there?
